# Sharing values in session between .jsp pages in OC4J

Tags: jsp, oc4j

I am developing a web server with multiple .jsp pages. OC4J (10.1.3.1) is being used. But I found that Parameters, that are saved in session in a .jsp page, cannot be retrieved in another .jsp page

Is there any hint ? FYI, OC4J is not customized by any means ...

Answer (score 0):

Objects stored in an `HttpSession` instance must implement the `java.io.Serializable` interface in order to be deployed with the `<distributable /> flag` in `web.xml`.

Read the article [Configuring the OC4J Instance](http://sqltech.cl/doc/oas10gR2/web.1012/b14013/configoc4j.htm). I think it could be helpful...

Comment: I am reading it. But is it strange that whenever I press F5 in Chrome Brwoser on the same .jsp page (where session ID is printed), the session ID is kept changed